# Store a char pointer from terminal input in C

Tags: c, terminal

I'm trying to create a simple calculator with input from the terminal. It is supposed to work like this:

```
./main.c 1 + 3
1 + 3 = 4
```

It is very simple code per se, but I have a problem with the terminal input. I have read a lot here at stackexchange about terminal input but I get this error while compiling:

```
error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
```

I do not know why. I have tried a lot of different ways to do it but it does not work. Here is the code, all I want to know is how to store the 1, + and 3 in the example above. The code I post here is just an example as how I can store the most "difficult" operation, in this case the + operator.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {

    char operator;
    int *operatorp;
    operatorp = &operator;

    operatorp = argv[2];

    printf("%c\n",operator);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `int *` and `char *` are not compatible.

Comment: If you want to input an expression directly in the command line you may expect problems on Unix/Linux systems...

Comment: Read what _undefined behaviour_ means. And avoid it! Also pay heed to compiler warnings. They are not for fun.

Comment: The `operatorp = argv[2]` assignment overwrites a value assigned by `operatorp = &operator`, rendering the firsr assignment useless. BTW the `operator` variable is never assigned any value, so printing it can't give any meaningful result.

Comment: Ty Olaf, I'm reading about it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct, you are trying to convert a int * to a char.

Just do

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int nbr1 = atoi(argv[1]);
  char operator = argv[2][0];
  int nbr2 = atoi(argv[3]);

  int result = 0;

  if (operator == '+')
    result = nbr1 + nbr2;
  printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

Comment: Sir, I salute you.

Comment: I have tried the atoi operator before, but I did it wrong. So I was not all the way out on a sunny beach. Ty again.

Answer (score 0):

argv is a matrix (2d array), that means argv[2] is an array of chars and you must do something like this:

char operator = argv[2][0];